# Custom Validator with @PathVariable and @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've to validate @PathVariable and @RequestParam in RestController but thats not happening, could you please let me incase if I've to add something in xml file or some where else. Can someone please let me know incase if I'm missing anything. Below is my rough program.

```
   @RequestMapping("messages")
    @RestController
    @Validated
    public class MessageResource {

        MessageService service = new MessageService();

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String getMessage(@Valid @Test @RequestParam("year") int year,@Valid @Test @QueryParam("start") int start,@Valid @Test @QueryParam("size") int size) {
            return "Hello";
        }

        @GET
        @RequestMapping("/test/{year}/{start}/{size}")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String getMessage1(@Valid @Test @PathVariable("year") int year,@Valid @Test @PathVariable("start") int start,@Valid @Test @PathVariable("size") int size) {
            return "Hellooooooooo";
        }
    }


import java.lang.annotation.*;
import javax.validation.*;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = Test.TestImpl.class)
public @interface Test {
    String message() default "error";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    class TestImpl implements ConstraintValidator<Test, String> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(Test arg0) {
            System.out.println("testingggggggggg");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String login, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1) {
            return Integer.parseInt(login) > 10;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if custom validators work for requestparams and path variables. I belive it works for @Requestbody.  In your case looking at your use case(which is u want to check if the integer variable is greater than 10 or not). This can be donw with this annotation `@Min(10)`

Answer (score 0):

Your validator is defined to validate RequestParam or PathParam with String type. Your types are int so it will not be triggered.